# Swift 2: guard in for loop?

Tags: ios, for-loop, error-handling, swift2

what is the correct way to use guard inside a for loop?

```
for (index,user) in myUsersArray.enumerate() {

    guard user.id != nil else {
        print("no userId")
        //neither break / return will keep running the for loop
    }

    if user.id == myUser.id {

        //do stuff

    }
}
```

Comment: Is the print part necessary?  This could be a use for `for in where`.

Comment: nope, just for "information" while developing that there might be some old dev-user-accs still around

Comment: The syntax is `guard let...` and the word you are looking for inside the else block is `continue`. But yes, a for in where would be better.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There are a few ways to make some conditionals:

You can put a condition for whole for. It will be called for each iteration

```
for (index, user) in myUsersArray.enumerate() where check() {}
for (index, user) in myUsersArray.enumerate() where flag == true {}
```

You can check something inside for and skip an iteration or stop the loop:

```
for (index, user) in myUsersArray.enumerate() {
    guard check() else { continue }
    guard flag else { break }
}
```

In your case I will be write something like this:

```
for (index, user) in myUsersArray.enumerate() {
    guard let userId = user.id, userId == myUser.id else { continue }

    // do stuff with userId
}
```

Comment: Looks good but you may add some words describing what you intend to get across.

Comment: @appzYourLife it's just a few examples where you can put a conditional

Answer (score 7):

@Arsens answer is correct but I think this is easier to understand

```
let ints = [1,2,3,4,5]

for (index,value) in ints.enumerate() {

        guard value != 1 else {
            print("Guarded \(value)")
            continue
        }

        print("Processed \(value)")
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
for (index,user) in myUsersArray.enumerate() {

    guard let userId = user.id else {
        print("no userId")
        continue;
    }

    if userId == myUser.id {

        //do stuff

    }
}
```